# Determining all the real values $\alpha$ such that series converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was given the task to determine all the real values $\alpha$ such that sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} $$\left(\frac{sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^\alpha$ converges. My initial idea was to approximate $sin(\frac{1}{n})$ with $\frac{1}{n}$, but it led me to nowhere. I would appreciate both the answers and the ideas.

Comment: Your initial idea is fine. Think of the general term as that which would be obtained by substituting $1/n$ in place of $\sin(1/n)$. This is permissible because the general term is positive. After that, you can formally use the ratio test for convergence of positive series.

Comment: That is exactly what I did, and the result was that alpha should be bigger than 2/3. However, I checked with Wolfram alpha and the series is divergent for alpha equals 2. So I do not know what I did wrong, I will try to find the mistake. Thank you anyway for approving my initial idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, then set $h(n):=\frac{\sin (1/n)}{1/n}$ so you can write

$$
\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\left(\frac{\sin (1/n)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\alpha }=\sum_{n\geqslant 1}(h(n))^{\alpha }\cdot \frac1{n^{3\alpha /2}}
$$

As $0<h(n)\to 1$ then the term $(h(n))^{\alpha }$ doesn't change the convergence properties of the series so its clear that for $\alpha \leqslant 2/3$ the series diverges and for $\alpha >2/3$ converges. Don't trust so much CAS (like Wolfram Alpha), the series is clearly convergent for $\alpha =2$.